# jQuery checkbox oncheck event does not work

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" id="lm27" value="27" checked="checked" 
       class="charr">ismea</input>
...
```

When the checkbox is toggled an event should be called. The element is selected by class. But the event is not called.

```
$(function(){
$('.charr').change(function() {
alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});

refresh_langlist();
});
```

---

full HTML if you may want to try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$('.charr').change(function() {
alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});

</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="lm27" value="27" checked="checked" 
       class="charr">ismea
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An `input` is a self-closing element, it doesn't have a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Try removing the function in line 1?

Comment: What is `refresh-langlist();`? You're invoking this function at DOM ready, is it throwing errors?

Comment: @DavidThomas, input here is copied from rendered page. in the source input is made by jQuery.

Comment: @tymeJV, I checked the function. it is ok.

Comment: @Mimo, still did not work.

Comment: So, just to be clear, your console has 0 errors?

Comment: How is jQuery creating that element, because it's invalid.

Comment: @DavidThomas, i updated the question. you may try the full HTML.

Comment: @gerrnar your full html is missing the document.ready function `$(function() {  //your event binding code})` which was in your example

Comment: seems should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/64Y2E/

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, thanks. now it did work on the sample. I will find the problem on the main project.

Answer (score 1):

Now I have realized the problem:

always call selector+event after new dynamically generated inputs. old events do not apply on the new elements even if they match.

Answer (score -1):

You can try changing the method you are using to check if checkbox is checked. Here is a (working) example of code to check if checkboxes are checked:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var checked = 0;

                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
                    var $b = $('input[type=checkbox]');
                    checked = $b.filter(':checked').length;
                    //alert('There are [' + checked + '] checked checkboxes');

                    if (checked > 2) {
                        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }else{
                        $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <h2>Allow up to three checkboxes to be checked, then disable all checkboxes on page</h2>
    <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bike">I have a bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="car">I have a car<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="spoon">I have a spoon<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="guitar">I have a guitar<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="boat">I have a boat<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="house">I have a house<br>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```